# How to clear cache of 1 stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I know that `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` will clear cache of all stored procedures in SQL Server.

But what I need is to clear cache of only 1 stored procedure. How can I do that?

The Stored Procedure name is `Rpt_RegionReport`. I don't want to execute the stored procedure with `WITH RECOMPILE` option.

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am testing this stored proc only and don't want to disturb other stored procs cache

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`DBCC FreeProcCache` has a single optional argument - the ID of the execution plan you want to delete.

You can find the plan you want to delete using `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans`, and then you can just use it as

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (0x0123456....);
```

Comment: awesome. I get the plan_handle with this query: `select cp.plan_handle from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st where OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid, st.dbid) = 'Rpt_RegionReport'` then store it in a variable and pass it to `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`

Answer (score 10):

Here is another way to delete the plan from the cache only for a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @PlanHandle VARBINARY(64);

SELECT  @PlanHandle = deps.plan_handle
FROM    sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS deps
WHERE   deps.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.SomeProcedureName') AND deps.database_id = DB_ID();

IF @PlanHandle IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DBCC FREEPROCCACHE(@PlanHandle);
    END
GO
```

Answer (score 8):

Wouldn't executing `sp_recompile` on the stored procedure work?

```
EXEC sp_recompile N'SP_Name';
```

Answer (score 4):

just find the plan using this query and clean the plan_handle

```
SELECT [text], cp.size_in_bytes, plan_handle
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle)
WHERE cp.cacheobjtype = N'Compiled Plan'
AND cp.objtype = N'Adhoc'
AND cp.usecounts = 1
ORDER BY cp.size_in_bytes DESC;

DBCCFREEPROCCACHE(0x0600010069AB592540C10089000000000000000000000000)
```

Plan_handle

Comment: I don't think you should have `cp.objtype = N'Adhoc' AND cp.usecounts = 1` as it might filter out the plan in question. You shouldn't assume that someone doing testing is hitting the proc from SSMS; the user could be hitting the proc from app code or a testing framework. And `usecounts` can "be incremented multiple times when using showplan", according to the MSDN page for [sys.dm_exec_cached_plans](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187404.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The Query given by @mohan might have some issues as it is filtering only objtype as Adhoc which means all other queries **excluding procedure** will show up here.

So Please Execute the following set of statements to selectively clear only selected procedure's execution plan.

```
--Enter Name of your Procedure. I have used here as 'SP_PrepareCustomers'. You should replace it with the name of your procedure. 
DECLARE @NameOfProcedure VARCHAR(255) = 'SP_PrepareCustomers'

DECLARE @planHandle VARBINARY(64) = (SELECT top 1 plan_handle
   FROM   sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp
          CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle)
   WHERE  cp.cacheobjtype = N'Compiled Plan'
          AND cp.objtype = N'Proc'
          AND cp.usecounts = 1
          AND TEXT LIKE '%' + @NameOfProcedure + '%')

IF @planHandle IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN     
      PRINT 'Procedure with name like ' + @NameOfProcedure + ' plan handle found with value as given below:'
      PRINT @planHandle   
      DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (@planHandle)
      PRINT 'Execution plan cleared for the procedure'
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
      PRINT 'No Plan was found for the selected procedure '
            + @NameOfProcedure
  END
```