# SQL Server Stored Procedure Returns More than 50 Rows Times Out, but Not All the Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very weird issue.  Our Sql Server database is version 2014.  During the startup of one of our WPF applications, many stored procedures are called with no issues.  One of the procedures returns 56 rows.  Some days, not all, it times out every time it's called.  When this happens, I can change the query in the procedure to SELECT TOP 49... and the timeout no longer occurs.  Once this happens, I then return the procedure to it's original state and the application then runs just fine!

Has anyone ever experienced this?  It's a very recent problem.  We haven't updated our database recently so I'm not sure what to do at this point.

EDIT:  Thanks for all the responses.  Clearing the cache doesn't make sense.  There are hundreds of procedures used in this application and this seems to be the only one causing a problem.  Plus, it's not a complex procedure at all.

The WITH RECOMPILE option seems to make the most sense to me.  I will try that and see if it solves the issue

Anyway, here is the procedure in question.  It selects from a view, which I have also included.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetUsersForRoleAndApplication] 
@roleCode varchar(25),
@systemCode varchar(25),
@systemUserId INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT 
    SystemUserId,
    UserName,
    DisplayName,
    RoleId,
    PSIApplicationId,
    RoleCode,
    RoleTitle,
    RoleDescription,
    SystemCode,
    SystemTitle,
    SystemDescription
FROM
    vwSystemUserApplication
WHERE
    RoleCode = @roleCode
    AND SystemCode = @systemCode
    AND (@systemUserId IS NULL OR SystemUserId = @systemUserId)
ORDER BY 
    DisplayName
END
```

And the View

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vwSystemUserApplication]
AS
SELECT DISTINCT
u.SystemUserId,
u.UserName,
u.DisplayName,
r.RoleId,
a.PSIApplicationId,
r.Code as RoleCode,
r.Title as RoleTitle,
r.[Description] as RoleDescription,
a.Code as SystemCode,
a.Title as SystemTitle,
a.[Description] as SystemDescription
FROM
SystemUser u
INNER JOIN SystemUserRole ur on u.SystemUserId = ur.SystemUserId
INNER JOIN [Role] r on ur.RoleId = r.RoleId
INNER JOIN PSIApplication a on r.PSIApplicationId = a.PSIApplicationId
WHERE
u.InactiveDateTime IS NULL
AND ur.InactiveDateTime IS NULL
AND r.InactiveDateTime IS NULL
AND a.InactiveDateTime IS NULL
```

Comment: You should include the execution plan. Also because this questions in fairly complex, I think you should transfer it to https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If altering the stored proc fixes it then the duplicate is likely what you need.

Comment: I have a feeling it is not related to the number of rows. I think if you did select top 100 it would do the same thing. The act of compiling the procedure is probably resetting something.

Comment: @mjwills are you suggesting the fix is to free the cache? That sounds like treating the symptom instead of the cause. Stored procedures should not require that on a regular basis.

Comment: Or extend the timeout, or use `WITH RECOMPILE` @Crowcoder (but obviously that is not without costs). In theory, they shouldn't require it - sure. But on larger systems the cached plan can be sub-optimal (I work on some very large SQL Server instances, and this kind of stuff is done once or twice a week for certain stored procs). Sometimes clearing / recompiling it is your best bet. Clearly it does work - since the OP is basically doing that already. There isn't much else we can suggest without seeing the code in question, which the OP seems reluctant to share).

Comment: or use the [optimize for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-ver15) hint. but do it carefully and test!

Comment: Did you check for any deadlocks? Do you have any transactions?

Comment: I'd suggest having a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30597429/how-to-clear-cache-of-1-stored-procedure-in-sql-server (that is the duplicate link I mentioned in my earlier comment).